# Need help writing bash script to move folders around

Tags: macos, bash, unix, directory, loops

What i need to do is replace the folder `amtlib.framework` into each Adobe app on my mac

if i do:
`cd /Applications; ls | grep Adobe`, this gives me all the folders which i need

here's some pseudo code:

```
apps = ls | grep Adobe
for each x in apps
   if (x/x.app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framwork) //if this folder exists
      add .bak extension //amtlib.framework.bak
      copy ~/Downloads/.../amtlib.framwork to x/x.app/contents/frameworks/
```

how would i implement this as a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for x in $( ls | grep Adobe) ; do
   if [[ -d "${x}"/"${x}".app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framwork ]] ; then 
      # add .bak extension # //amtlib.framework.bak
      #? mkdir "${x}"/"${x}".app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framwork.bak
      #? /bin/mv "${x}"/"${x}".app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framwork {x}/${x}.app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framwork.bak 
      /bin/cp ~/Downloads/.../amtlib.framwork to "${x}"/"${x}".app/contents/frameworks/
   else
      : # ??? what do you want to do if there's not 
   fi
done    # loop
```

If you're likely to have spaces in your dirnames, (not sure if OSX support `-print0`), but try

```
 find . -name 'Adobe' -print0  \
 | while read x ; do 
    if ....
```

As an FYI, assignments in bash are done like (without spaces around the `=`):

```
apps=$(ls | grep Adobe)
```

Depending on the situation then, you'll want to use `"$apps"`, or just plain `$apps`, which leaves each word in the list as a separate token. (If there are spaces in your filename or path, 1 path/file is now 2 words, and will cause issues). There are also array notations to use, `apps=( $(ls | grep Adobe) )`, and using those vars like `${#apps[@]}` (number of elems), `${apps[@]}` (all elems), `${apps[1]},` (first elem) is possible.

Also, it's not clear what your intent with `add .bak extension` is for. My best guess is my 2nd option, `/bin/mv ... .bak`.

IHTH.

Comment: Just one comment: **do not parse the output of `ls`**. Use globs instead: `for x in *Adobe*; do`

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's a typo error in the original post that's made its way throughout the examples given.  The folder you are looking to rename/replace is amtlib.framework, *not framwork*.

Second, for some reason, the test for existence of the .bak directory is not working for me, even when I split this out to a separate if-then statement it doesn't work:

```
cd /Applications
for x in *Adobe* ; do
printf "$x \n"
printf "%s" "  "
if [ -d "$x/$x.app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framework.bak" ]; then
     printf "removing old bak... "
  fi
if [ -d "$x/$x.app/contents/frameworks/amtlib.framework" ]; then
    printf "moving... "
    printf "copying... "
    printf "%s\n" "done!"
  else
    printf "%s\n" "nothing to do here!"
  fi
done
cd ~
```

Finally, understanding the goal you will fail to update a couple of apps that have an additional folder level (e.g., Acrobat Pro and Illustrator).